# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function React

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-hooks

I'm learning React from this [channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ij8CfkAY2RAGb-tmkNwQHG). Recently, I stumbled upon React Hooks from [here](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM?t=1598). So, I tried to convert a class based component to hook based. Here is my class based component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddNinja extends Component {
    state = {
        name: null,
        age: null,
        skill: null,
    }
    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addNinja(this.state);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" onChange={ this.handleChange } />

                    <label htmlFor="age">Age: </label>
                    <input type="number" id="age" onChange={ this.handleChange } />

                    <label htmlFor="skill">Skill: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="skill" onChange={ this.handleChange } />

                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is my converted component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n0lw4wo550?module=%2Fsrc%2FAddNinja.js

But I'm getting following error:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the versioning issue. because Hooks are currently in React v16.7.0-alpha and being discussed in an open RFC https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html and you are using React 16.6.0 in you sandbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React hooks are available in React `v16.8.0`. updated your react and react dom version to `16.8.0`.

```
"react": "16.8.0",
"react-dom": "16.8.0",
```

Here is your code with updated verion:https://codesandbox.io/s/qq90900xr4